# Generalized linear mixed model for multiple count variables

Tags: logistic, glmm, count-data

I recently did a study where I asked participants to edit a partially written article. They had to select at most three sources that they found most useful for a written task. Participants were divided into 4 conditions:

- either they receive a reading guide for sources,
- the partially written article,
- both or
- neither.
  The sources were of three types: very relevant, tangentially relevant, not relevant.

I am interested to know the likelihood of participants to select the very relevant sources over the tangentially and not relevant sources. Does this mean that I need a statistical method that can accommodate multiple count variables (which in this case is the source types)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a logistic regression. Also, you have tagged with mixed-models, why? I can see no need here for a mixed model, what should the random effects be?